# Matlab Code Generation for Handle Classes Reallocated in a Loop

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I am running into some behavior in Matlab Coder that I don't completely understand. To simplify, here's a short example that exhibits the behavior.  If I have a handle class defined as:

```
classdef somehandleclass < handle %#codegen

properties
    something
end

methods
    function obj = somehandleclass(initval)
        obj.something = initval;
    end
end

end
```

and a short function to use it:

```
function result = runsomehandleclass %#codegen

obj = somehandleclass(0);
for i=1:6
    obj = somehandleclass(i);
end

result = obj.something;

end
```

...then I build the `runsomehandleclass` function with a simple build script:

```
cfg = coder.config('mex');
cfg.GenerateReport = true;
codegen -config cfg runsomehandleclass
```

I get the following error:

> ??? Unsupported allocation. An allocated handle object escapes the loop.
>   Error in ==> runsomehandleclass Line: 5 Column: 11

I understand the text of the error, clearly I'm creating new instances of `somehandleclass` each time through the loop. My question is: why should that be an error? In this simple example it is trivial to work around this, but the problem occurs in a much larger code base where deep in another function a handle class is reinstantiated with substantially different settings. I can (and have) worked around this, but the new solution is much less elegant. In reality, there's no leak here, as handle classes are supposed to be deleted when their handle is overwritten.

If I remove the inheritance from `handle` and make the class a value class, the error goes away and the mex compiles as expected, however in my actual application, I do wish to have a handle class.

Is this expected behavior by the compiler? Also, is there a workaround, for instance is there some way to explicitly delete `obj` before I construct a new instance into `obj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/memory-management-of-handle-objects-in-generated-code.html#buzy035), it's your case.

In `obj = somehandleclass(i);`, `obj`, which was initialized outside of the loop, referred to a `somehandleclass` object created inside the loop. In other words, use value class if you want to use it inside a loop.

Comment: That's more or less a restatement of my question.  Yes, I know it's created outside the loop and then (presumably) destroyed and recreated over and over in the loop. This is just a simple example of the issue; in my actual application the instantiation happens deep in other code, but the error and result are the same. It is desirable to have it be a handle class and to call the constructor anew in the loop. There is, as far as I can tell, no reason this code should not be valid or compile. It works in MATLAB directly.  Is this somehow a prohibited use case?

Comment: ...if it is a prohibited use case, can you point to a document for MATLAB Coder that indicates that handle classes cannot be initialized in a loop?

Comment: since it's matlab, not C++. you use its features and must also live with its limits. talking abt class and oop, matlab has never been a good choice nor 1 of the mainstream ones. Did you see the link? It said very clearly `A Variable Outside a Loop Cannot Refer to a Handle Object Created Inside a Loop`

Comment: I did not intend to make a restatement, i pointed out where did Matlab say that your case is not accepted with code generation. And it is the answer for your question about expected behavior of compiler.

Comment: Aha, thanks for adding the link. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ...or else your link was there the whole time and I missed it. My apologies.